# How to store partially-used construction adhesive tube

Tags: adhesive, caulking, storage

I use small 295ml caulking tubes of [PL Premium](https://www.princessauto.com/en/tan-premium-construction-adhesive-caulk/product/PA0009042532) construction adhesive for small repair jobs around the house.

I usually only use a small amount of adhesive at a time; not a full tube.

[image]

How can I store the partially-used tube for easy re-use?

As we know, construction adhesive is strong stuff. I've tried taping the tip of the tube shut to avoid adhesive curing and creating a blockage. But that hasn't worked; the adhesive dries so I can't get any out of the tube for subsequent use.

Comment: Short answer, you'll get a few months at best. Consider it the cost of doing business.

Comment: That's certainly been my experience. You could try vacuum-packing it, if you had a suitable machine, but realistically it seems to start slowly curing as soon as it's opened.  If you need it, it's worth the cost of some wastage.

Comment: If you know you only need a small bit for a project, PL Premium does come in a 4 oz tube—but it costs about the same as a 10 oz tube, and you can't use it in a caulk gun.  So I guess it depends how much you want to contribute to waste vs convenience, because it's gonna cost you about the same either way.

Comment: I typically let it dry, there is no way to stop it. After it does and I need it, I carefully split the nozzle with a razor knife, pry open the end and pull out the cured tip. I use tape to repair the slice I made and carry on with the tube.